# Rails 4: strong parameters and array of scalars must be listed last on permit?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

See the `people_controller#person_params` method for the code version of the question:

```
# person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Attributes:
  # - names (string)
  # - age (integer)

  # Combine: ["a", "b", "c", ...] => "a,b,c"
  def names=(values)
    self[:names] = values.join(",") if values.present?
  end
end

# people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @record = Record.new(person_params)
    @record.save!
  end

  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(
      # Works fine
      :age,
      names: []

      # Works fine
      { names: [] },
      :age

      # Does not work (SyntaxError)
      names: [],
      :age
    )
  end
end
```

The question is, why does the `names` scalar array not work when you list it at the beginning without wrapping it as a hash?

The http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters doc examples don't wrap scalar arrays with a hash, but they aren't very complex examples, either.

Is this expected behavior for `strong_parameters`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a `strong_params` thing, but rather how ruby is reading list of attributes. In Ruby, you can only omit the curly brackets around the hash when it is **the last argument for the method**, so this call:

```
any_method(arg1, arg2, key: value, foo: :bar)
```

is read as:

```
any_method(arg1, arg2, { key: value, foo: :bar })
```

You cannot omit the brackets if the hash is not a last argument though, hence this:

```
any_method(arg1, key: value, arg2)
```

will raise a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for that; I knew that at one point but wasn't even thinking about it in this regard.